# c socket send large file occur broken pipe error

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send a file using a C socket.

I've made a server using pthread. The server reads the file by the size of the buffer, and sends it to the client as much as the read size.

It works well for small size files, But When I'm trying to send a large file,  like an mp3 file (more than 5MB), it does not work well. The client sends a request again, and the pipe is broken.

My server is running on OSX and I'm using a browser as the client.

> When html file has mp3 resource as tag, mp3 sends OK.(I called `localhost:9999/index.html`) but when I call mp3 file directly (e.g `localhost:9999/music.mp3`), broken pipe error occurs. ( `localhost:9999/image.jpeg` is OK)

I added ignoring SIGPIPE, but still the broken pipe error occurs.

I can't understand it. What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t pthread;
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void *pthread_read_and_write(void *arg);
int writeToClient(int newsockfd, char* msg);
void sendError(int newsockfd);
void sendResponseHeader(int newsockfd, char *httpMsg, long contentLen, char *contentType);
void requestHandler(int newsockfd, char *reqMsg);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    int portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd,10);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1){
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
            error("ERROR on accept");
        pthread_create(&pthread, NULL, *pthread_read_and_write, (void *)(intptr_t)newsockfd);
        pthread_detach(pthread);
    }
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

void *pthread_read_and_write(void *arg){
    int newsockfd = (int)arg;
    char reqMsg[500];
    int n;

    bzero(reqMsg,500);
    n = read(newsockfd,reqMsg,499);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("========Request Message======\n%s\n",reqMsg);
    requestHandler(newsockfd, reqMsg);
    printf("=============================\n");

    return NULL;
}
void requestHandler(int newsockfd, char *reqMsg){

    printf("client socket : %d\n", newsockfd);

    char file[100];
    char *method = strtok(reqMsg, " /");
    strcpy(file, strtok(NULL, " /"));
    char tmpFileName[100];
    strcpy(tmpFileName, file);
    strtok(tmpFileName, ".");
    char *extension = strtok(NULL, ".");
    printf("method : %s\n", method);
    printf("file : %s\n", file);
    printf("extension : %s\n", extension);
    if(strcmp(method, "GET") == 0 || strcmp(method, "get") == 0){

    }else{
        sendError(newsockfd);
        return;
    }
    if(strcmp(file, "HTTP") == 0 || strcmp(file, "http") == 0){
        strcpy(file , "index.html");
    }
    printf("compare success\n");
    long fsize;
    char type[20];

    if(extension == NULL || strcmp(extension, "html") == 0){
        strcpy(type, "text/html");
    }else if(strcmp(extension, "jpeg") == 0){
        strcpy(type,"image/jpeg");
    }else if(strcmp(extension, "gif") == 0){
        strcpy(type,"image/gif");
    }else if(strcmp(extension, "mp3") == 0){
        strcpy(type, "audio/mpeg");
    }else if(strcmp(extension, "pdf") == 0){
        strcpy(type, "application/pdf");
    }else{
        strcpy(type, "text/plain");
    }
    printf("compare success\n");
    printf("type : %s\n", type);
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL){
        sendError(newsockfd);
        return;
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    char rcvBuf[BUFSIZ+1];
    int fd;
    printf("reading file...\n");
    if((fd = open(file, O_RDONLY)) <0 ){
        printf("sending error...\n");
        sendError(newsockfd);
        printf("send error OK\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("open fd OK\n");

    char *httpMsgOK = "200 OK";
    printf("sending header...\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sendResponseHeader(newsockfd, httpMsgOK, fsize, type);
    printf("send header OK\n");

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    int n;
    bzero(rcvBuf, BUFSIZ + 1);
    if(fd >= 0) {
        while((n=read(fd, rcvBuf, BUFSIZ)) > 0){

            printf("sending rcvBuf : %d, remain : %ld\n", n, fsize-=n);
            int res = send(newsockfd, rcvBuf, n + 1, 0);
            if(res <0) {
                char errMsg[100];
                sprintf(errMsg, "ERROR writing to socket __sock : %d __", newsockfd);
                error(errMsg);
            }
            bzero(rcvBuf, BUFSIZ + 1);
        }
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    printf("closed client socket\n");

}
void sendError(int newsockfd){
    char *msg = "<html><body><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></body></html>";
    sendResponseHeader(newsockfd, "400 Bad Request", strlen(msg), "text/html");
    writeToClient(newsockfd, msg);
    close(newsockfd);
    printf("closed client socket\n");
}

void sendResponseHeader(int newsockfd, char *httpMsg, long contentLen, char *contentType){
    char resMsg[40];
    char conLen[100];
    char conType[50];
    sprintf(resMsg, "HTTP/1.1 %s\r\n",httpMsg);
    sprintf(conLen, "Content-length: %ld\r\n", contentLen);
    sprintf(conType, "Content-Type: %s\r\n\r\n", contentType);

    printf("response message\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", resMsg, conLen, conType);
    writeToClient(newsockfd, resMsg);
    printf("send resMsg OK\n");
    writeToClient(newsockfd, conLen);
    writeToClient(newsockfd, conType);
    printf("send conType OK\n");
}

int writeToClient(int newsockfd, char* msg){
    int n =  write(newsockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    return n;
}
```

and the result is below

```
========Request Message======
GET /run.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4


client socket : 4
method : GET
file : run.mp3
extension : mp3
compare success
compare success
type : audio/mpeg
reading file...
open fd OK
sending header...
response message
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-length: 5187428

Content-Type: audio/mpeg


send resMsg OK
send conType OK
send header OK
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5186404
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5185380
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5184356
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5183332
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5182308
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5181284
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5180260
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5179236
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5178212
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5177188
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5176164
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5175140
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5174116

.....

sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 2593636
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 2592612
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 2591588
========Request Message======
GET /run.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9999/run.mp3
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Range: bytes=0-


client socket : 6
method : GET
file : run.mp3
extension : mp3
compare success
compare success
type : audio/mpeg
reading file...
open fd OK
sending header...
response message
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-length: 5187428

Content-Type: audio/mpeg


send resMsg OK
send conType OK
send header OK
send header OK
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5186404
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5185380
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5184356
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5183332
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5182308
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5181284
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5180260
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5179236
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5178212
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 5177188

.........

sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4781924
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4780900
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4779876
sERROR writing to socket __sock : 4 __: Broken pipe
ending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4778852
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4777828
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4776804
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4775780
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4774756
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4773732
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4772708
sending rcvBuf : 1024, remain : 4771684
(EXIT)
```

#### Edit 2017.10.13

- `int` to `ssize_t`
- When I use `read`, `send` and `write`, using `ssize_t` not `int`
- determine request message is `NUL`
  I added below code after call `read`

  ```
  if(reqMsg[0] == 0){
      printf("req msg is null\n");
      close(newsockfd);
      return NULL;
  }
  requestHandler(newsockfd, reqMsg);
  bzero(reqMsg, 500);
  ```
- In `writeToClient`, write until all msg is sent. I added below code.

  ```
  long toSend = strlen(msg);
  while(toSend > 0){
      n = write(newsockfd, msg, toSend);
      printf("write :  %ld\n", n);
      toSend -= n;
  }
  ```

#### Edit 2017.10.13 - 2nd

When I use `write`, check its return value is `0`. If return value is `0` `close` client socket and `return` for quitting pthread.

but still same error occurs.

Comment: Read [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm sorry for uploading full code.

Comment: Probably many things but, to start with, why does calling 'void sendResponseHeader' require a mutex lock round it?

Comment: 'Server read the file by the size of the buffer and send it to the client as much as the read size'.......'while((n=read(fd, rcvBuf, BUFSIZ)) > 0){'.....'int res = send(newsockfd, rcvBuf, n + 1, 0);'.   n != n+1.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand why use mutex lock round that. I saw the example using mutex like that. So I guessed mutex lock can help broken pipe problem and wrote mutex lock round that function.

Comment: Yep. I tried 'int res = send(newsockfd, rcvBuf, n + 1, 0);' at first time. but I saw that I should use +1 for null, so I changed n to n+1. but it made same issue.

Comment: Forget NUL termination here.  You cannot use NUL-terminated char arrays to transfer binary data - it contains, in general, embedded NULs.  If you read n bytes, send n bytes.

Comment: I got it. but after changing n+1 to n, broken pipe error occur.

Comment: OK - you have another problem.

Comment: How do you know that `n = read(newsockfd,reqMsg,499);` reads *only* the "request message"?  If the client sends the terminating `NUL`, your `printf()` won't output all the data read.  Second, you're `writeToClient()` function can write less than `strlen(msg)` bytes and you'll never know.  Third, `read()` and `write()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.  Little things like that *matter* in TCP socket programming - the connection is a *stream* with no message boundaries.  If you're sloppy, it can work one time and not work the next.

Comment: I change things you said. but still same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> Server read the file by the size of the buffer and send it to the client as much as the read size..

No, it is not.

```
while((n=read(fd, rcvBuf, BUFSIZ)) > 0){..
```

This loads exactly `n` bytes into your buffer, no more, no less.

```
int res = send(newsockfd, rcvBuf, n + 1, 0);
```

This sends `n+1` bytes to your client.  The extra byte is not valid in the current buffer data.  And this is a buffer overflow if `n` is exactly `BUFSIZ`.

Comment: I tried `send(newsockfd, rcvBuf, n, 0);` at first time. but same issue happens. and I changed n+1 to n now. but still happens broken pipe error.

Answer (score -1):

> I added ignoring SIGPIPE, but still the broken pipe error occurs.

SIGPIPE can be ignore, but OS will probably kill you if you get too many pipe error.

Your problem is that you don't understand that SIGPIPE mean you have an error in your program:

> The SIGPIPE signal is sent to a process when it attempts to write to a pipe without a process connected to the other end.

This is clear, you try to write on a socket that has been close. So the solution is to look where in your program you forget to correctly handle error.

```
n = read(newsockfd,reqMsg,499);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
```

Here if `n` equal `0` the socket has been close.

```
int res = send(newsockfd, rcvBuf, n + 1, 0);
if(res <0) {

writeToClient(newsockfd, msg);

writeToClient(newsockfd, resMsg);
printf("send resMsg OK\n");
writeToClient(newsockfd, conLen);
writeToClient(newsockfd, conType);

int n =  write(newsockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

See, you never verify that you write at least 1 byte (ofc write can return 0 if msglen is 0 too).

In a true server, you always read before write, with read you could handle end of file but in your code you don't handle correctly the client.

Comment: I added `close` client socket and `return` when `n` is `0`. but still same error occurs.